# Kuzzle-SDK-SearchResult query

Tags: iot, kuzzle

I am currently trying to SearchResult query in kuzzle android sdk earlier it was working but after upgrading the version I have an error when I perform SearchResult I get following error :  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: io.kuzzle.sdk.Exceptions.ApiErrorException: Wrong type for argument "from" (expected: integer)
Any idea of the reason ? Thanks

Comment: you need to add details like version, modules, *log files* or a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that the community can better understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error message gives you the answer: `Wrong type for argument "from" (expected: integer)`

I suspect that your `from` argument is not an integer type.